# Toshiba Windows 7 Upgrade disk no longer working

Tags: windows, upgrade, toshiba-laptop

Back in 2009 I bought a Toshiba Satellite L510 laptop for my sister. It came with Vista SP1, but registering gave my a free Toshiba Upgrade disk to Windows 7. I took the time to do DVD backup from a Toshiba utility and ordered the upgrade disk.

When I received the upgrade disk, I installed it: all was working perfectly.

Last week, the hard disk failed. I bought a new one and reinstall Vista from the backup DVD. Work as expected, no problem at all. I then inserted the windows 7 upgrade disk and the fun started:

- The link to the ToshibaUpgradeAssistant.exe was broken. I had to find it browsing the Toshiba support web site (using google of course, the web site is so well designed)
- I installed it and run it
- It gives me an error "This model can't be upgraded to Windows 7" ... but I did it in the past, the only thing that has changed is the hard drive!
- I called the Toshiba support with no success. (It could be your new hard disk drive, try to update your bios, pay us 30$ to get more help)

Any advice?

I also tried updating my BIOS (from v1.49 to v1.50) with no more success.

Comment: what did toshiba support say?

Comment: Its could be your new hard disk drive, try to update your bios, pay us 30$ to get more help.

Comment: The ToshibaUpgradeAssistant.exe looks at your bios to be sure it is a qualifying PC, evidently something does not look right when it checks. There is a secondary way to check your serial [here](http://www.csd.toshiba.com/cgi-bin/tais/support/jsp/bulletin.jsp?soid=2450599)

Comment: Is that the exact error message you posted?

Comment: I will edit the question, but the exact message was "This model can't be upgraded to Windows 7". I also tried to update the BIOS (v1.49 => v1.50) but still got the same message.

Comment: There is a bios tattoo that is permanent and will not be corrected by a bios update, but sometimes the tattoo block of the bios becomes corrupt or unreadable, this is common on HP's, but suspect that is your issue, did you check your serial on the toshiba website I linked to?

Comment: I checked and all is ok. The thing I don't understand is that it work once with the "factory hardware" and "factory os" back in 2009. I just changed the Hard Drive and re-installed the factory os with the backup disk made by the Toshiba utility.

Comment: You checked the bios tattoo?

Comment: I checked the web site you linked to. In fact, this is were I was able to find the ToshibaUpgradeAssistant.exe.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a legal key, you will have to look for W7 upgrade media (dvd) and use that rather than the toshibacrappa upgader. Media is everywhere, bittorrent, friends, neighbors, relatives, co-workers.

Yours is an upgrade key, so it will not work with all W7 install media, it needs to be upgrade media.

Or go buy another upgrade copy from Fry's or other retailer, or internet store.